# How to separate the print area for printing in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, list

I am currently fetching the complete user details and lists it into a html table from the database table.I need to take the print of that particular list so i use the `window.print()`
to do it. I place the entire html table which needed to be printed inside a `div` called  `<div id="printableArea">` and uses the following javascript to do the job.

```
function printDiv(printableArea)
     {
        var tabl = document.getElementById('tablePrint');
        var row = tabl.rows[0];
        var cell = row.cells[0];
        cell.innerHTML = '';
        var printContents = document.getElementById(printableArea).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

But the problem is that i am getting the `pagination` button `delete` button in the bottom of the page along with the check boxes for selection corresponding to each row.How can i avoid those? Also i need to take the print out page to be in a grid format.

Need suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest hiding them. Then, when printing is over, show them again, if need be.

This can be done in 2 ways:

- Load another stylesheet, which hides the unneeded div's

either [this](http://developerssolutions.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/load-css-dynamically/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598899/unload-css-from-webpage) should do it

- Hide them via Javascript like so (using jQuery):

`$('#idOfDivToHide').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

you can put the buttons outside your printable div area.
and use that printable area for printing only.
you can jquery to do this.
you can refer this:
http://www.gontztech.com/tips-and-instructions/web-design-tips-and-tutorials/printing-a-specific-section-of-web-page-without-hiding-any-content.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference rajesh