# Use a new CSS file to override current website's

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My website has currently 3 CSS files that are automatically included as a part of the website and I do **not** have access to the source i.e. *index.html* of the website **but I do have** access to the CSS files of my website.

I am trying to use my own style to override my websites CSS files and create a new CSS file that would contain all the styling that I would like to overwrite on my website.

I have tried using `@import url(css4.css)` and I have placed that at the top of my last CSS file but that wouldn't overwrite the last CSS file's styling.

How can I achieve this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="currentCSS1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="currentCSS2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="currentCSS3.css">   
<!-- How to add this below just by using CSS? -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newCSS4.css">
```

Comment: u can use !important at every line of ur css, but, erm, u have to get access to index.html and just remove unnecessary  csses from header)

Comment: Why don't you just delete all of the content of css3 and replace it with @import url(css4.css), then copy the contents of the old css3 to css4, and override the rules here?

Comment: I can't change the css3 because its something that the developers of the website keep updating which is why I don't want to delete anything that is already available because with future updates for that website, I would like to make sure my changes are in a seperate file rather than on one of the source files as it may get overwritten during upgrades.

Comment: Your @import change would get removed in that case anyways if they were updated. What other files do you have access to?

Comment: Yes my import would get removed which is why I'm looking for a bullet-proof solution.

Comment: You need to make your selectors more specific than those currently used. eg. `.some-item` becomes `body .some-item`

Comment: I thought @import was only supposed to be kept at the top (even before any comments) rather than the bottom?

Comment: I don't know where you people are getting the idea that @import can be included anywhere but the top!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Stop upvoting incorrect comments

Comment: Exactly, I was looking for that link to support my statement. Thanks @ilia

Comment: Can you not remove the CSS file by file name/URL and then add yours via JS?

Comment: I don't want to play with the source file/files already present because of future updates to the website. Not intending to use JS because there are tons of pages where the css is being loaded.

Comment: you can not override styles by placing your css file as the latest style element. You should override by changing your selectors in the your css file. for example if there is rule like "div { bacground-color: red; }" and want to change background color to green use "body div { background-color: green;}" check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: You essentially want to change part of the DOM (either removing a previous `link` or adding a new `link`).  Unfortunately, you cannot achieve DOM manipulation with CSS (that's what javascript lives for).  I would look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598899/unload-css-from-webpage to unload the previous CSS link and then create a JS file to load in your new CSS.

Comment: Is this only for your eyes? Many browsers (Firefox and Safari I am certain) allow you to load custom stylesheets. You set the custom stylesheet from the browser options and it's as if it's the last stylesheet for every website you visit.

Comment: I am trying to understand the question a little better. Please tell me if you have access to the webserver at all or is the new stylesheet just something for your eyes only and to be tested in your workstation only.

Comment: @yavuzkavus, that is not correct.  If two rules have equal specificity, the later one wins. Moreover, adding 'body' to the rule to override an earlier rule is bad practice - it is not repeatable and not self-documenting.

Comment: Yes I do have access to the webserver but not the index.html. I have access to the css and js files but I would prefer to do it using the css files.

Comment: @TheNewbie, are these statements correct? 1) You cannot modify the HTML of the page at all, and therefore cannot include another CSS file. 2) You can modify the CSS files, but the developers may modify them again later and remove any changes you made.  Hence you cannot permanently modify the CSS files.  3) You cannot/do not want to use Javascript (despite tagging the question with Javascript and JQuery).  If all of these things are true, there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes the above statements are correct and I possibly might have found a solution myself. If I get it working properly, I would post the solution below.

Comment: @phari, you are right, if two selectors are same, the last one overrides. I dont know whether selectors in the css files The Newbie mentioned are same or not.

Comment: The selectors are the same and I have made some selectors even more specific just to make sure I'm just targeting the ones I need. So all that is good.

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/  which is a great starting point to reset any css rules you might want to get rid of. For more details, visit this other link: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @TheNewbie, do you need this solution for just one personal page, or several pages? Also, can you add more files to the server? if so, what language is the server running? PHP for example? I have ideas in mind.

Comment: There are several pages affected by the three stylesheets I mentioned. I can add more files on to the server.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Besides using `!important` that most answers are advising you to use, this is a matter of **[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity/)**

> ### The concept
>
> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.
>
> ### How is it calculated?
>
> The specificity is calculated on the concatenation of the count of
>   each selectors type. It is a weight that is applied to the
>   corresponding matching expression.
>
> In case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.
>
> Some rules of thumb
>
> - **Never** use !important on site-wide css.
> - **Only** use !important on page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css (from ExtJs or YUI for example).
> - **Never** use !important when you're writing a plugin/mashup.
> - **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important

**can be represented by 4 columns of priority:**

> **inline** = *1|0|0|0*
>
> **id** = *0|1|0|0*
>
> **class** = *0|0|1|0*
>
> **element** = *0|0|0|1*
>
> **Left to right, the highest number takes priority.**

---

***Here is a snippet with a Full example of a CSS specificity***

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}

/*CSS Specificity */

/* SPECIFICITY: 0/1/0/0 */
#id {
  background-color: green
}

/* SPECIFICITY: 0/0/1/0 */
.class {
  background-color: yellow 
}

/* SPECIFICITY: 0/0/0/1 */
section {
  background-color: blue 
}
  
/* ------------ override inline styles ----------- */

/*to override inline styles we  now use !important */

/* SPECIFICITY  0/0/1/0 */

.inline {
  background-color: purple !IMPORTANT /*going to be purple - final result */ 
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div class="inline" style="background-color:red">
          <!--SPECIFICITY 1/0/0/0 - overridden by "!important -->
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

***Now here is the Full snippet step by step***

---

#### ID: *GREEN*

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}

/*CSS Specificity */

/* SPECIFICITY 0/1/0/0 */
#id {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div>             
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### CLASS: *YELLOW*

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}

/*CSS Specificity */

/* SPECIFICITY  0/0/1/0 */
.class {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### ELEMENT: *BLUE*

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}

/*CSS Specificity */

/* SPECIFICITY  0/0/0/1 */
section {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### INLINE STYLE: *RED*

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div style="background-color:red">
        <!--SPECIFICITY 1/0/0/0 -->
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### OVERRIDDEN INLINE STYLE: *PURPLE*

```css
/*demo purposes*/
body {margin: 0;padding: 0}
div,article {min-height: 200px;height: 100%;width: 100%}
/*CSS Specificity */

/* SPECIFICITY  1/0/0/1 */

section > div {
  background-color: purple !IMPORTANT
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="class">
      <section>
        <div style="background-color:red">
        <!--SPECIFICITY 1/0/0/0 -->
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

#### *You can calculate the specificity of your element(s) [here](http://specificity.keegan.st/)*

---

#### Note:

***A must read on this subject***

- [Inheritance and cascade](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade)
- [CSS Specificity](http://blog4coders.com/css-specificity)
- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a fun solution no one has mentioned.

**Facts:**

1. You cannot modify the HTML of the page at all - **no problem!**
2. You can modify the CSS files, but the developers may modify them
   again later and remove any changes you made - **not a worry.**
3. You cannot/do not want to use Javascript and JQuery - **fine by me.**
4. You can add more files on to the server - **Excellent!**

Let's do some .htacess hacking for fun and profit!

### Document root .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*?)css3.css(.*?) $1hackedCSS3.php$2 [L]
```

Result: *hackedCSS3.php* is silently served instead of *css3.css* on every request.

REF: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

### hackedCSS3.php file:

```
<?php

// Send the right header information!
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

// Output the css3.css file
echo file_get_contents("css3.css");
?>

// Add your CSS here with any neat !important or override tricks (read: specificity)
div { ... }
```

**Bonus:**

You could expand this solution to include all three `.css` files in this one `.php` file (but only serve, say, *css3.css* and send the *css1.css* and *css2.css* to a black hole with *.htaccess*), and use clever regular expressions to remove/modify those developer's CSS without touching any of their files. The possibilities are tantalizing.

### Addendum:

> Can you be a bit more specific on where to include these files?

The .htaccess file should be in the **document** root directory of the website. This is where www.example.com/index.html would load index.html

> Should the hackedCSS3.php file be in the same directory as the other
>   css files?

It can be in any directory you specify in the .htaccess file. The document root is fine. Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)css3.css(.*?) $1hackedCSS3.php$2 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)css3.css(.*?) /folders/you/want/hackedCSS3.php$2 [L]
```

> Should our css content (where you specified // Add your CSS here...)
>   should be within html style tags?

No. Treat your CSS code in that section as if it were a .css file. You do not need `<style>` tags.

Comment: Where do I find this .htaccess file please?

Comment: Just create it with a text editor. Name it ".htaccess" and drop it in the root of your server. Notice the leading dot. Here is a handy doc: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Comment: @TheNewbie Hi, any luck with this solution? I can hep you with more questions about this

Comment: I'm on the case and I'm trying. Will post an update if I get it to work.

Comment: I have few questions;
1. Can I do the same thing from the virtualhost file. I already have RewriteEngine on
2. Can you be a bit more specific on where to include these files. I figured that the .htaccess file should be in the root directory of the website, Is that the ROOT folder or the root of the website?
3. Should the hackedCSS3.php file be in the same directory as the other css files? css1, 2 and 3 are in separate directories at the moment
4. Should our css content (where you specified // Add your CSS here...) should be within html style tags?

Comment: @TheNewbie Hi, I've answered your excellent questions in my answer. As for vhosts, you can enable rewrite there or in the .htaccess file. It's fine to leave it in .htaccess. This is usually enabled by default. Also, replace `RewriteRule ^(.*?)css3.css(.*?) $1hackedCSS3.php$2 [L]` with `RewriteRule ^(.*?)css3.css(.*?) /hackedCSS3.php$2 [L]` if you want the hackedCSS.php in the document root

Comment: "Let's do some .htacess hacking for fun and profit!" Upvote for good sense of humor and original answer.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Been following your steps as mentioned.

Comment: To test if your setup is correct, navigate to your http:// ... /css3.css. At least the hackedCSS3.php should display in your browser. Can you confirm this?

Comment: If you are having trouble, would you mind sharing one of the css urls? Let's verify that it is being rendered as the php file

Comment: How'd that work out? I still want to help you with this

Comment: I found that unfortunately PHP wasn't installed on our server and I couldn't get it to install on Apache, been trying a few sources but no luck so far. The server has been installed as java. Would you be having a similar solution along those lines or give me some pointers on installing PHP?

Answer (score 6):

To use CSS only, the best way would to use [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)'s developer tools and find the various style you want to overwrite.

The for each of the style you find that need adjusting then use the `!important` modifier.

```
.newClass {
  color:red !important;
}
```

Another way would be to write unique css class names and again use `!important` if you need. The real trick here is in specificity. If an identifier is more specific the rule will be applied.

[6.4.1 Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

> 6.4.1.4
>   Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same
>   weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.
>   Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>   declarations in the style sheet itself.

```
<a class="my-most-awesome-link its-really-cool">Most awesome link</a>

.my-most-awesome-link.its-really-cool {
  text-decoration:none !important;
  color:red !important;
}
```

If you are desperate you could use javascript to remove the unwanted css.

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wayejahigi/2/edit) for a working example.

[I found this interesting technique](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)

```
<script>
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
    var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none"; //determine element type to create nodelist from
    var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none"; //determine corresponding attribute to test for
    var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement);
    for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
      if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1){
          allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]); //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
      }
    }
}

removejscssfile("css1.css", "css") ;
removejscssfile("css2.css", "css") ;
removejscssfile("css3.css", "css") ;
</script>
```

Comment: Can't/Don't want to use Javascript.

Comment: The first two methods will work. If you want to provide one specific example, I could answer your problem more directly.

Answer (score 3):

In your new CSS file, add `!important` to the block of code, for instance:

if you have this on css1.css:

```
 h2{
 color:#000;
 }
```

In css4.css put the same element, but with `!important`, as follows;

```
 h2{
 color:#ccc !important;
 }
```

Therefor, `!important` will force that this style will be by all means the style set for the element to which it's applied.

Comment: Please read my question again. That's not what I asked. I asked how can I get this new css file as my last css file without having any access to the source code of the website and just use css to do that.

Comment: This is as close to a correct answer as this question is ever going to get.  It is not possible to inject a new CSS file as the last one purely by modifying other CSS files, but adding !important as described here **has the same effect**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@import url('css4.css')` in one of your existing css page. Then use specificity to be highlighted your new code as bellow:

Html :

```
<ul class='ulclass'>
 <li class='liclass'>
  <a class='aclass>The text</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

css1.css :

```
.aclass{
   color : red;
}
```

css4.css :

```
ul.ulclass li.liclass a.aclass{
   color: green;
}
```

Then you will have `green` color in your `a` element

Answer (score 2):

write a new css, and use id of elements rather than class. Also use !important in css.

Answer (score 2):

### An alternative: Rely on the cascade, instead of specificity

A number of solutions here recommend using `@import` to include your `css4.css` file and then modifying the selectors therein to have a greater specificity or to use the `!important` declaration, but there is yet another way.

Paste the entire contents of `css4.css` at the end of `css3.css`. In this way, you need not rely on `!important` or specificity, because the cascading inheritance will adopt your rules at the end of the file if they are of equal specificity.

With this method, you are sacrificing modularity for easier implementation.

**Example of pasting, relying on cascade:**

```css
/* Contents of css3.css */
.mycooldiv {
    font: bold 1.2em sans-serif;
    color: tomato;
}

/* Pasted contents of css4.css */
.mycooldiv {
    color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycooldiv">Hello World</div>
```

However, it would be easy enough to create greater specificity by simply prepending `html` to the beginning of every rule in `css4.css`, if you don't want to paste it at the end of `css3.css`. This is preferred to adding `!important` where it works.

**Example of importing, relying on greater specificity:**

```css
/* @import of css4.css with greater specificity */
html .mycooldiv {
    color: lime;
}

/* Contents of css3.css */
.mycooldiv {
    font: bold 1.2em sans-serif;
    color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycooldiv">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer. The way that I have tried to achieve this is:

1) Say my css3 is the last CSS in the list and I have all my changes in css4. I have made a copy of css3 and called it "**css3-Original.css**" and added my css4 in the same folder. I then created another css file called "**css3.css**" (because that is the last one it takes from the list) and added imports of my Original css3 first and then my overriding css4.css file as given below:

**css3.css** (The new one)

```
@import url("css3-Original.css")
@import url("css4.css")
```

This is the best way I found it to work. This way although I know that my css3.css file will change on updates but I know how I can replace it very easily and quickly. I have used !important in my css4.css wherever necessary (if required) but basically because its the last css file, it uses that styling as compared to any previous ones (unless they are !important).

Thanks for the suggestions guys. I finally managed to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're question correctly, adding `@import url(css4.css)` to the top of `css3.css` does import your stylesheet into `css3.css`. But your styles are being overridden by the styles in `css3.css`. This is because of [Cascading Order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) and [Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). In order for your `css4.css` styles to be used, your selectors must have a higher specificity than the selector in `css.3.css` you are trying to override.

Example: `<h1>` tags will be colored red.

```
body h1 { //this is more specific
   color: blue;
}

h1 { //this is less specific
   color: red;
}
```

**But since you're `@import url(css4.css)` line of code will get removed every time the developers update the `css3.css` file** this is not a "bullet-proof solution"

Do you have the ability to add any javascript to the site? If so you could use the following solution

**jQuery**

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css4.css">');
```

**Javascript**

```
var head = document.head
  , link = document.createElement('link')

link.type = 'text/css'
link.rel = 'stylesheet'
link.href = 'css4.css'

head.appendChild(link)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11833777/2687861

Comment: Don't really want to use any javascript because there are tons of pages that I'd have to modify in order to get this to work properly. I'd prefer to get this done just by using CSS.

Comment: If there was a single js file included on all the pages it wouldn't be that difficult. There isn't a solution in css with the perimeters you've given. Perhaps if you gave more detail into your specific situation we could come up with a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have checked almost all the pages and the js files vary on each. The only files that are common are the css files.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your only option is to use `@import` and re-add it back in every time the developers update the css3.css file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have to agree with ***phari***.

Quote:

> 1) You cannot modify the HTML of the page at all, and therefore cannot include another CSS file. 2) You can modify the CSS files, but the developers may modify them again later and remove any changes you made. Hence you cannot permanently modify the CSS files. 3) You cannot/do not want to use Javascript and JQuery). If all of these things are true, there is no solution to your problem.

Commented by *phari* on *Mar 26 at 14:29*

Let me break it down. I will try my best to explain why there's no solution (correct me if I am wrong at any of these options);

**Option1: Using jQuery or Javascript.**
*You cannot modify the HTML of the page at all!! You do not want to use jquery nor javascript.*
This means that all answers to your question mentioned on this page which involves jquery or javascript are disregarded. *This does not mean the answers given on this page are wrong*. In your case it's not possible.

**Option2: `@import url(css4.css);`**
Your website has 3 css files that are automatically included as a part of the website, but unfortunately, you *DO NOT* have access to *ANY* of these css files. You can not place this piece of code in css3.css, or any of these files.
You can modify the CSS files, but the developers may modify them again later and remove any changes you made, which means `@import url(css4.css);` can also be removed.
Also using `@import url(css4.css);` would be completely useless. You'll have to place `@import url(css4.css);` at the end of css3.css, but this won't work because *@import rules must always be first in a document*. If I am not mistaking ilia (who commented on Mar 23 at 9:42) meant the code can be place anywhere in the file. `@import url(css4.css);` must be at the top. The link ilia provided as "prove" also specify that it's a **requirement** to place it at the beginning.. Check the two links below.
More Info visit http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatimport.htm or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import#Specifications. 
Option 2 is disregarded too.

I don't think there could be another way to do what you want to do.
Hence, there is no solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For duplicate CSS definitions, the last definition will have precedence.

If the added css4.css file is actually referenced after the "3 css files that are automatically included", then the css4.css file's definitions should override the prior duplicate definitions from these other files.

If you are not seeing the results that you expect, use the "view source" option of your browser to confirm the sequence in which the CSS files are referenced. Also use the "Developer tools" of the Chrome browser or the "Firebug" add-on for the Firefox browser to find out how the browser is interpreting the CSS definitions to yield a result that you did not expect. These tools should provide insight to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can just overwrite the text in the css file available to you, the style which you want from previous css file you can copy that code in the you can add with that new code refresh your website the result you need appears