# How to override inline styles in a child div?

Tags: c#, html, css, inline-styles

I have two `div`s like below

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>    
</div>
```

Now in the `child` div, I see a style called `height` with some pixels when I inspect it. I am surprised how its not applied to the parent `div`.

I want to override the style to `100px` from its `30px`.

My application is an angular and css3 html5, web api mvc based app.

How to do it?

I tried this

```css
div[style] {
 height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The child div has a class correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But when I inspect, the style is not from the class, its getting injected (Inline) from somewhere, don't know where. But my requirement is, I want to make that style="height: 30px" as 100 PX.

Comment: @dippas: thank you very much for asking, I am afraid no where in my CSS I have such 30 specification for height. It is not from a class, it is rather inline when I inspect and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that inline style is being inserted dynamically and you don't know how you can't change (you really should debug till you find out how is being inserted) then to be more specific than inline styling, only using `!important`

**NOTE** this is one of the extreme cases that `!important` should be used. Otherwise **AVOID IT**

```css
.child {
  background: red;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="height: 30px">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269359/3448527) with more details regarding this subject.