# CSS3 :not() selector not working on sibling element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a simple layout where I want the text red if it is not in the `footer` element.  It works with `p` tags, `a` tags etc.

But when I try it with `footer` tag it doesn't work.

My code is below:

```css
p {
  color: #000000;
}

 :not(footer) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<footer>This is a footer.</footer>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the parent which is `body` (otherwise `footer` will inherit red from `body` as per your rule stated), in order for `:not(footer)` to work.

Regards to `p` its a matter of [CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206832/use-a-new-css-file-to-override-current-websites-css/29269359#29269359)

```css
p {
    color: #000;
}

body > *:not(footer) { /* note that having :not(footer) is the same as *:not(footer), the wildcard is not necessary */
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<footer>This is a footer.</footer>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<p>This is some text in a p element.</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
:not(footer) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

That sets *all* elements to red, except the `footer`.

The problem is that the rule sets the `body` element to red. Then the `footer` inherits the color.

So your rule actually works (the sibling is excluded), but the footer gets the color nonetheless through inheritance.

Instead or targeting all *siblings* (except `footer`), target all *children* (except `footer`). This eliminates the inheritance loophole:

```css
body > :not(footer) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<footer>This is a footer.</footer>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need a parent element to nested for `:not()` selector to work so here in your code `body` tag'll work as parent element

```
body > :not(footer){
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: What if I have h3 tags outside of the footer and one inside of the footer. How would I say I want all h3 tags except the h3 tag in the footer to have a certain styling?

Comment: add class to footer inside footer and write this h3:not(.css){color: red;}...see this pen u'll understand (https://codepen.io/satyajit11/pen/XzoWeB)

Comment: I can't do it without adding a class? and using :not(footer) instead of class name?