# Modifying the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.css.map

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC5 project. When I created a project, I decided to move the fonts into the Content folder to keep my root folder clean. This meant I had to update some of the paths in the projects, CSS files.

Now today when I deployed to Azure, couple of elements were missing. I managed to track it down and I updated:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') etc.....;
}
```

by removing **"../"** from the beginning of the url in the files **bootstrap.min.css** and **bootstrap.min.css.map**.

Is this ok? Is there another easier way to update these URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really recommended to edit bootstrap.min as it already has been minified. Meaning all whitespace and extra characters has been removed. It is better for you to make another css file and override the needed changes in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Considering I don't know how to override it, and also I just checked the size of the file didn't increase and it went down by 15 bytes, I might take the easy way out and check it in.

Comment: you can refer to this to understand more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206832/use-a-new-css-file-to-override-current-websites-css

Comment: Thank you so much. That also helps.