# I can't use the same CSS property with a different value when toggling a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `ul` tag with an id of `sideNav` and I'm toggling a class on it with JavaScript.

For the id styles, I have a `left` attribute with the value of `0`, while on the class I have the same attribute with a value of `-100%`.

I have tried a lot of things to discover what the problem is and I've come to the conclusion that I can't use the same property with a different value in this case.

Why? Do you know any alternatives? Am I missing something here?

**This is my code:**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("burgerWrapper");
var sideNav = document.getElementById("sideNav");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sideNav.classList.toggle("activeNav");
})
```

```css
#sideNav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.activeNav {
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sideNav">
  <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can, in fact, use the same property within different classes or ids. You just need to override the previous value with `!important`. So in your case you would write your `.activeNav` class this way: `left: -100% !important;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the  CSS specificity, the id is more specific than a class therefore overriding the latter

You can see how CSS specificity works in an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269359/3448527)

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("burgerWrapper"),
  sideNav = document.getElementById("sideNav")

btn.addEventListener("click", () => sideNav.classList.toggle("activeNav"))
```

```css
#sideNav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

#sideNav.activeNav {
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sideNav">
  <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="burgerWrapper">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS Cascade is very important to learn, Your properties are being overwritten because of specificity.

Your `#sideNav` has a specificity score of 1.0.0, and the `.activeNav` has a specificity of 0.1.0, so the id wins. You need to be more specific, like here in example: `#sideNav.activeNav`, it has a score of 1.1.0, so it will override all the mentioned above and it should work,
You can read here more about the CSS cascade and specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("burgerWrapper");
var sideNav = document.getElementById("sideNav");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sideNav.classList.toggle("activeNav");
});
```

```css
.body {
    position: relative;
}

#sideNav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

#sideNav.activeNav {
    left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <ul id="sideNav">
            <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="burgerWrapper">press</button>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
#sideNav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

#sideNav.activeNav {
  left: -100%;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't post an answer, just a comment but i can't make comments yet