# how to isolate html element from being affected by multiple css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extention that inserts HTML code into a webpage, but its design gets affected by the host webpage's css.

js

```
var button = document.createElement("button ");
button.id = "btn_btn_btn";
button.innerText = "pres button";

document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].prepend(button);
```

css

```
#btn_btn_btn{
   background-color: rgb(229, 97, 97) !important;
   border: none !important;
   height: 100px !important;
   color: white !important;
   font-size: 15px !important;
   text-align: center !important;
}
```

is there a way of having it only be affected by my css file without adding important to every attribute an element can have.

Comment: Unless you can use a more specific selector than the webpage uses, then you'll have to override their styles with `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar thread from 5 years ago and it has the answer

[Use a new CSS file to override current website's CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206832/use-a-new-css-file-to-override-current-websites-css)

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity this would help you even in future.. Avoid `!important`  as it may affect any other element (rare case) with the same class in the webpage. Try to make your selector more specific.. like.. `#container #parent #button.btn_btn_btn` it will override all global styles that are less in precedence.