# Dynamically switch CSS files in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have 2 css files: `light.css` and `dark.css`, also have a `ThemeSwitch` component which represents the `select` element, this element has handler for handling change of value (the value is either `light` or `dark`). The question is: is there any way to include one of these css files according to the ThemeSwitch value: if value is `light` - import/include `light.css`, if value is `dark` - then import/include `dark.css` (like a theme switcher)

Comment: You could do something like this: https://erikmartinjordan.com/select-css-variable-react

Comment: @Andrew Hulterstrom. I've tried this, but it works only if you need to choose theme once at the start, but I want to be able to switch them during the runtime no matter how much times

Comment: Oh, so you just want to be able to turn off one of the files at a time? Maybe this answer would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598917/15351640

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-lazy or react-suspense libraries for conditionally changing components or CSS files.

**Below is the example of react-lazy library**

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

const Theme1 = React.lazy(() => import("./Theme1"));
const Theme2 = React.lazy(() => import("./Theme2"));
const THEME_1 = "1";
const THEME_2 = "2";
export const ThemeSelector = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(null);

  const changeTheme = () => {
    debugger;
    setTheme(theme === "1" ? "2" : "1");
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (theme !== THEME_2) {
        setTheme(THEME_2);
      } else {
        setTheme(THEME_1);
      }
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        {theme === "1" && <Theme1 />}
        {theme === "2" && <Theme2 />}
      </React.Suspense>
      <button type="checkbox" value={theme} onClick={changeTheme}>Change Theme</button>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It looks like a solution, but the dynamic import gives an error: ```Cannot find module './css/dark.css' or its corresponding type declaration```